# Find files with particular removed text and stage them in git

Tags: git, git-stage

Suppose I've removed the text 'foo' from a lot of files in my repository, and I want to commit that change.

But there are also lots of unrelated changes.

How do I find just those files and stage them?

Comment: For bonus points: is there a way to stage JUST those diff chunks which have that change?

Comment: Getting just the diff hunks is a lot more difficult. You've provided an answer that works for the entire files. Consider also `git diff-files` to compare index (staged copy) to working copy, as a plumbing command; you should be able to combine this with `-S foo` to find places where the count of `foo`s has changed, and post-process that to get just removals.

Answer (score 1):

`git grep`'s `--cached` option appears to search in changes that are *UN*staged (which looks like a bug, as it's not what its docs say, and it's not how `git diff` treats its `--cached` option).

Doing `git grep --cached foo` gets:

```
somefile.txt: foo: true
```

To stage these, use `cut` to extract just the filenames: `git grep --cached foo | cut -d : -f 1`:

```
somefile.txt
```

and then xargs to stage that list: `git grep --cached foo | cut -d : -f 1 | xargs git add`.

Comment: Use `git grep -l` to list just the file names. (Note that they're relative to the current subdirectory within the repository, by default.) You are in fact searching the *staged* blobs, which *do* have the `foo: true` line here. It's the diff from staged to unstaged where `foo` has been removed, and searching the working tree, you won't find `foo`.